# Picasso - Image downsizing before downloading for better performance

Tags: android, performance, picasso

I have a list of images that I have to download from the server and show them in a listView in android app. They are of varying ratio, and since I would to make each ImageView to match the device's width, I cannot fix their height.

I also know that I could improve the performance by downsizing the image before downloading, just as what Picasso is doing with fit() and resize().

I am using Picasso for my project. The problem is, I cannot use Picasso's fit() and resize() methods, which are methods to downsize image before downloading, if I do not know the height of the imageView beforehand.

So I tried with other approaches. I am wondering if transform would do the downsizing as well?

```
new Transformation() {
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
                        int targetHeight = deviceWidth;
                        double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
                        int targetWidth = (int) (targetHeight / aspectRatio);
                        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
                        if (result != source) {
                            // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
                            source.recycle();
                        }
                        return result;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String key() {
                        return "transformation" + " desiredWidth";
                    }
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "downsize the image before downloading".

Picasso (and everything else) downloads the original image as-is, and only then does calculations to scale the image according to the container's dimensions.

If you don't use neither `fit()` nor `resize()`, Picasso will load the image at full resolution: that is, the resolution of the original image.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to download directly a small image you should start thinking on another server that makes that dirty job of downloading and downscaling the image and then serve it to your app

Comment: thx for correcting me, I didn't think of that. Then, what should I do with Picasso to increase the performance when the image is first loaded? Does the above code with transform method help? What else could I do to improve it?

Comment: You can simply call `fit()`, it should take care of correctly resizing the image according to the size of its container. If, on the other hand, you decide the container size at runtime, you can call `resize(width, height)` and combine it with either `centerCrop()` or `centerInside()`, depending on what the final result must be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Thumbor](http://thumbor.org/) service to crop and resize images before downloading. Square has a nice Java client for it - [Pollexor](http://square.github.io/pollexor/). And special [Picasso RequestTransformer](https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/master/picasso-pollexor) for Pollexor. That said, you'll get all the preprocessing extracted to the backend.